# Name for matrices with orthogonal (not necessarily orthonormal) rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, orthogonality

Is there a name for a matrix whose rows (or columns) are non-zero orthogonal vectors ?

It seems to me that "orthogonal matrix" would be a good name, but this is already taken -- it refers to a matrix whose rows (or columns) form an *orthonormal* set of vectors.

Comment: None that I can think of. How about Scaled orthogonal matrix? Just made that up.

Comment: It's a great pity that the name "orthogonal matrix" is already taken. These kinds of matrices are quite common in my business (geometric modeling). They correspond to non-uniform scaling operations. Maybe I'll have to call them "non-uniform scaling matrices" if the world of mathematics can't offer anything better.

Comment: I would probably reserve that name for the diagonal matrices used in coordinate transformation for scaling with unequal scaling coeffecients in the coordinate directions but that's just me.

Comment: Pseudorthogonal?

Comment: So, since the 0 vector is orthogonal to everything, some of the columns could be 0? ... what is so bad about saying "matrix with orthogonal columns"?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/386050/28900).

Comment: This question has been asked a few times. The term "orthogonal matrix" for $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^TA=(AA^T)=I_n$ is a bit unfortunate, athough widespread. Unitary is less ambiguous, and works in the real case, like in the complex case. Then you could call orthogonal a matrix whose columns are orthogonal. But that's too late for a change of habits.

Answer (score 5):

An orthogonal matrix refers to a matrix whose rows *and* columns are orthonormal. This is a key property of orthogonal matrices, one which ultimately requires these matrices to be square.

Suppose $A$ is rectangular matrix ($n > m$) with row and column vectors which are [a] non-zero and [b] orthogonal to one another.  We know,

1. Orthogonal vectors are also linearly independent.
2. The row rank of $A$ equals the column rank of $A$, $\textrm{rank}(A') = \textrm{rank}(A)$.

Then, (1) and (2) together suggest $\textrm{rank}(A') = \textrm{rank}(A)$, or $m = n$.  But this a contradiction.

Restricting the rows *or* columns to be orthogonal and non-zero is a departure of sorts.  A semi-orthogonal matrix $B$ is a non-square matrix with real entries having the property that either (1) $BB' = I_m$ or (2) $B'B = I_n$, with the respective true case representing an orthonormal basis.

The case you speak of, a matrix whose rows *or* columns are orthogonal (not orthonormal), could be described as a semi-orthogonal matrix under a scaling transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, two non-orthogonal rows mean a shear transformation, don't they? If this is right (and I'm sure somebody will let me know if I'm wrong), then you could call them *shear-free* matrices. **Updated to add:** Somebody let me know I was wrong, as predicted...

But a pure shear is volume-preserving, so this might be misleading. How about *row-orthogonal* matrices?

Comment: No, orthogonality of rows bears no relation to shear. Scaling the first vector by $2$ has orthogonal rows, then composing with a rotation by $45^\circ$ produces non-orthogonal rows $\sqrt2({1\atop1}~{0.5\atop-0.5})$, but this is not in any way a shear transformation.

Comment: @Marc: Yes, you are quite right.